# Splunk extract a value from string which begins with a particular value

Tags: splunk

Could you help me extract file name in table format.
Here  the below field just before file name is always constant. "Put File /test/abc/test/test/test to /test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test destFolderPath: /test/test/test/test/test/test/test/abc/def/hij"

This is an event from splunk
2021-04-08T01:03:40.155069+00:00 somedata||someotherdata||..|||Put File /test/abc/test/test/test to /test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test destFolderPath: /test/test/test/test/test/test/test/abc/def/hij/CHARGEBACK_20210407_060334_customer.csv

Result should be in table format: (font / format doesnt matter)

### File Name

CHARGEBACK_20210407_060334_customer.csv

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the original event/field ends with the file name, you should use this regular expression:

```
(?<file_name>[^\/]+)$
```

This will extract the text between the last "/" and the end of the event/field ("$").

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/J6bU3m/1

Now you can use Splunk's `rex` command to extract fields at search-time:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="2021-04-08T01:03:40.155069+00:00 somedata||someotherdata||..|||Put File /test/abc/test/test/test to /test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test destFolderPath: /test/test/test/test/test/test/test/abc/def/hij/CHARGEBACK_20210407_060334_customer.csv"
| fields - _time
| rex field=_raw "(?<file_name>[^\/]+)$"
```

[image: Here is a screenshot.]

Alternatively, you could also use this regular expression since you mentioned that the file path is always the same:

```
| rex field=_raw "abc\/def\/hij\/(?<file_name>.+)"
```